# Current session get invalidate after catching exception but i have to make more query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I try to execute this code

```
@Transactional
@Controller
public class MyController{

        ....

        @RequestMapping(..) 
        public String MyMethod(...)
        {
          ....

          try {
            ao_history_repository.save(new AoHistory(..));
          }
          catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            System.out.println("history already exist");
          }
          ....
          model.addAttribute("...", my_respository.findAoToDetail(id) );

          return "...";
        }
```

But when i got duplicate entry Exception i catch it but after i got a other Exception

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in persistence.AoHistory entry 
                   (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
```

I know that When a ConstraintViolationException is thrown it invalidates the current session but how can i  reopen a new session and a new transaction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you write, you need a new transaction. From your code snippet it looks like the simplest thing would be to move `@Transactional` from the controller to the repository classes. As an alternative, you could add a service layer and move `@Transactional` there.

A different approach would be to pre-check the entity object before trying to save it in the entity manager, so that exception is never thrown.